# Reverse Proxy SSL container

Tags: tls, proxy, http-proxy

Technically and security wise, can a reverse proxy act as a "container" for SSL certs ? Meaning, for example currently my web server is running on ssl (https). Can I move the SSL cert to the reverse proxy and let it handle SSL connections to the web server. And my web server will revert back to port 80 normal web traffic? thanks

Comment: Unless you are blocking port 80 traffic other than from the reverse proxy, this is rather dangerous - you are providing an SSLStripping service for your own site. You need to make sure that only the reverse proxy can access the content intended to be protected by SSL. If you are running mixed traffic then keep it on different ports..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. In fact all big load balancers (eg. F5 Big-IP) work in this mode by default.

Comment: hi, thanks. Can I confirm with you, the web server do not need to install SSL cert. I will only install the cert on F5 and F5 will take care of it. Right? thanks

Comment: Exactly. Most very big sites works that way.